# Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.beta in parallel

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to use Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.Beta Nuget packages in paralell and referenced them like this in my csproj-File:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraphBeta" Version="1.25.10" Aliases="MSGraphBeta"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.25.10"/>
```

Within my existing code, only the Graph SDK should be used, so I set no alias there. This means I import it with:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
```

Never the less, I still get the following error:

```
The type 'GraphServiceClient' exists in both 'Microsoft.Graph.Beta, Version=4.50.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=4.34.0.0,
```

I'm working with asp.net core, targetFramework is net7.0.
What am I missing to use both SDKs in parallel?

Comment: Is [`extern alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) what you need? - _You might have to reference two versions of assemblies that have the same fully-qualified type names. For example, you might have to use two or more versions of an assembly in the same application. By using an external assembly alias, the namespaces from each assembly can be wrapped inside root-level namespaces named by the alias, which enables them to be used in the same file._

Comment: Check the doc: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet#using-the-beta-client-along-with-the-v10-library

Comment: Thank you! It mostly works as expected, but I get this error in ASP.net core MVCs Startup.cs:

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraphExtensions.AddMicrosoftGraph(Microsoft.I
dentity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityAppCallsWebApiAuthenticationBuilder, string, string)' and 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraphExtensions.AddMicrosoftGraph(Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityAppCallsWebApiA
uthenticationBuilder, string, string)'

at line:
.AddMicrosoftGraph("https://graph.microsoft.com/1.0", "user.read user.readbasic.all")

Comment: @Aggys sounds like you need to ask another question?